# Resolve public DNS names via VPN ins AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, vpn

I want to connect to my VPC via client VPN and use my local mysql client to access my RDS instance. I am also hoping  that I can ssh into my servers using their public DNS name. My client VPN endpoint is configured to give me a IP from the pool (not used by any VPC subnet!): `172.1.0.0/16`

Its is associated to subnet `172.2.0.0/16`

I have set authorizations and added routes to access:

`172.2.0/16 (default route)
 0.0.0.0/0 (internet access)`

I allow all traffic from my VPC endpoint security group to the DB & Servers.

I am able to connect the VPN. I get a IP address from the 172.1.0.0/16 CIDR range. I can access the internet while VPN is connected. I can ssh onto my servers using their private IP's.

I played around with a Route 53 inbound resolver but that did not affect anything.

Comment: [Route53 resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-route-53-resolver-for-hybrid-clouds/) is likely the proper way to do this. Alternately for a temporary solution just put the current IP into your hosts file - it will work for a while, but you may need to manually update if the AWS hosts change.

Comment: @Tim I appreciate your input. I will do some more troubleshooting using it.

Comment: Why add internet access via the VPN? You can enable split tunnel, and only go via the VPN for your network, the rest, like the internet, will go via your internet connection instead of the VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually enabled me to get public dns names resolved was to add the resolver IP's to my /etc/resolv.conf file as highest nameserver on the list. However due to extreme slow internet speeds (35kbps) this product seem unusable.
[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/be052z/aws_client_vpn_incredibly_slow_speeds/) discusses how to get faster speeds but that's a lot of config for something that should be a simple service. I don't want the overhead of all these configurations.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution can be use VPC's default DNS resolver in your VPN's DNS settings.

What is your VPC's CIDR range? E.g. if it is `10.0.0.0/16` then the default resolver would be at `10.0.0.2`. This IP can be added into VPN's DNS configuration to automatically resolve the DNS.

Credits: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/resolving-private-dns-queries-using-aws-vpc-resolver/

NB: I will update this answer when I find a good solution with Route53 resolver.

Comment: Cool. I will stay posted for your update. I will have to revisit this issue as i decided to use a VPN proxy server in my cloud.

Comment: This also works for *.internal domain names, which I had trouble with resolving when using VPN client endpoint.